# What happens to hbase region reassignment?

Tags: hbase

The master can decide to move region from one region server to another as the result of load balance operation.

Does the data for a reassigned region get moved over to a different data node in case of reassignment? If so, will there be a downtime involved when the transfer happens?

Answer (score 1):

A feature of HDFS is that data written to disk is available in several replicas in the cluster (default is 3). In previous versions of HBase files were scattered all over the place and there is [work underway to create complete shadow regions](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-10070) also see ([HBase read HA using timeline consistent region replica](http://www.slideshare.net/enissoz/hbase-high-availability-for-reads-with-time))

Regardless of data locality a regionserver will read data remotely if needed so if there is missing data it will be read over the network and overtime will be available locally where the regionserver runs.

The availability gap is around the writes that weren't flushed to disk and need to be replayed from the WAL